# Have Active-Active Azure Sql Server Database replication

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We can have passive read-only asynchronous real-time sync-up for Azure SQL database, for disaster recovery.

But our requirement is to have real-time sync-up between both active read-write databases to provide low latency to customers in different locations of the world.

for example:

> I'm providing e-commerce website, I will update data in one of the
>   database server and other connected databases in sync with this
>   database should get updates.
>
> Users from different servers of the world will get connected to their
>   nearest data center for low latency. If someone buys something or puts
>   some review, it should get updated in all other databases.  In this
>   way we need active-active database sync.

We explored multiple items on this, but did not find anything relative.

Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has [Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15), but you need to ensure in the application that conflicting changes are not introduced on multiple nodes.

SQL Server also has [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15), which allows updates at any subscriber, and supports custom conflict resolution.

These are both available on SQL Server VMs.  Limited [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/replication-with-sql-database-managed-instance) options are available on Azure SQL Database Managed Instance.  Azure SQL Database also has [Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data).

Azure Cosmos DB also supports [Multi-Master](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-multi-master).

In either case multi-master introduces significant cost/complexity.  Often it's better to just have a single writable master with regional readable replicas.  In that configuration the application needs to connect to the global master for writing, but can read from a local replica.  For this pattern you can simply use [Failover Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auto-failover-group?tabs=azure-powershell).